# HTML is not being indented

Tags: vim

I have just created a file `.html`. When I run `set filetype?` I get `filetype=html`. Then I select this code:

```
<div>
<span>
</span>
</div>
```

and press `=` but the code is not indented... I don't have problems to indent `php` files for example using the same procedure.

Comment: It works for me; my `indentexpr` option is `indentexpr=HtmlIndent()` for html files. Which is yours?

Comment: @yolenoyer do you mean what I get from `:4verbose setlocal indentexpr` ? I get `indentexpr=`

Comment: Are you enabling filetype indentation?  Usually you'll have something like `filetype plugin indent on` but sometimes people just have `filetype plugin on` or even `filetype on`.  I suspect that may be what is happening here.  Check by issuing `:filetype` while in vim.

Comment: @RandyMorris from `:filetype` I get `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`. By the way: after pressing `=` I get the message `4 lines indented` but they are not indented as I said before.

Comment: what vim version is this? You might need an update to your runtime files.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt 7.4.712 Im on Ubuntu 15.10. I insalled vim through `apt-get`.

Comment: @ziiweb try updating the indent script if that helps

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt how? could you give me any hint? I search for "vim update indent script" but I don't get anything useful.

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/indent/html.vim

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt thanks, I have just updated it, but the problem persists..

Comment: check, if the script has been sourced: `:scriptnames` Also I wonder why your vim says indent: ON, when it looks like it does not read that file. Where did you put that file and did your restart vim?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt this is the output of `:scriptnames`: https://gist.github.com/Ziiweb/9cbb2eb0d6498a6e40e0 . Yes, I restart vim.

Comment: The indent script isn't sourced. Are you sure about the `:filetype plugin indent on`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt wait, the output before was from `gvim`, the output in vim is this: https://gist.github.com/Ziiweb/e572d79260f94e8a5a89 but the problem is the same, event after running `filetype plugin indent on`. :/

Comment: When you're in an `html` file, try to run manually `:so $VIMRUNTIME/indent/html.vim`

Comment: @ziiweb if you are running the `:filetype plugin indent on` command interactively then you need to reopen your html file before the effects of that command will be seen.  Either put that in your `~/.vimrc` file or run `:e!` to reread the file after running `:filetype plugin indent on` interactively.

Comment: @yolenoyer after `:so $VIMRUNTIME/indent/html.vim` and `=` the lines are indented, but 8 spaces..